# Seeking SRTM 90m data

Tags: dem, data, elevation, united-states, srtm

I'm looking for 90 meter resolution SRTM data to coverage a large state in the Western US.  I used to use Derek Watkins' awesome tile grabber for SRTM90: https://dwtkns.com/srtm/
but as he explains on the site, it no longer works because of some backend issues.  So he points to CGIAR: https://cgiarcsi.community/data/srtm-90m-digital-elevation-database-v4-1/ but the google drive link is restricted and despite requesting access, I still cannot open the link.
And this CGIAR website literally has a blank area under the "Data Download" section: https://bigdata.cgiar.org/srtm-90m-digital-elevation-database/

Where do folks go to get SRTM 90m data now?

USGS EarthExplorer doesn't appear to provide the 90m SRTM data product: https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

The National Map only has 1 arc-second resolution or better: https://apps.nationalmap.gov/downloader/#/

Comment: Try this link: https://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/srtmdata/ and select the images you want to download. I have not tried it, but it seems it works.

Comment: If you are looking for open data then opendata.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask

Comment: @ahmadhanb That works but it also might be the worst user interface I've ever had to use to find data.  Blank grid of boxes with no way to track which is which without linking to a new page is really a deficiency.  I guess I can email CGIAR and ask them what it would take to improve it?

Answer (score 2):

SRTM 90m (plus the 30m dataset and some others) are still hosted on the MEASURES server: https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MEASURES/

The folder  `SRTMGL3.003` is 90m SRTM.

To make it easier to download the tiles in an automated way, I made a list of all the [individual urls for SRTM 90m here](https://www.opentopodata.org/datasets/srtm90m_urls.txt):

```
https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MEASURES/SRTMGL3.003/2000.02.11/N00E006.SRTMGL3.hgt.zip
https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MEASURES/SRTMGL3.003/2000.02.11/N00E009.SRTMGL3.hgt.zip
https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MEASURES/SRTMGL3.003/2000.02.11/N00E010.SRTMGL3.hgt.zip
https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MEASURES/SRTMGL3.003/2000.02.11/N00E011.SRTMGL3.hgt.zip
https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MEASURES/SRTMGL3.003/2000.02.11/N00E012.SRTMGL3.hgt.zip
...
```